# Cannot open a PowerShell file directly from folder, when a folder in the path has a space in it

Tags: windows, windows-10, powershell

I tried searching for this, but only came across people who were missing quotations around their path, when they wanted to run a PowerShell .ps1 file. However, this is not my problem. I have the following folder structure:

```
C:\Users\user\Desktop\repositories\project folder\subfolder
```

As you can see, there is a folder called `project folder`. Because of that, when I double click a .ps1 file in Windows file explorer, it will open PowerShell but immediately close again. No output or anything.

I can only assume space in the path is the issue, that causes PowerShell to not find the file. When the file is directly moved into `repositories` folder, it works flawlessly.

Any clues how I can fix this? It's quite annoying that I have to:

<kbd>SHIFT</kbd>+<kbd>RIGHT_CLICK</kbd> the folder -> open PowerShell -> write the .ps1 name -> hit <kbd>enter</kbd>

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Windows 10 64-bit. PowerShell 5.1

How to double click a powershell script with a space in the path.

Add `-file` to the registry, create a regfile, or [download](http://dfellows.rf.gd/3.reg) the regfile.

```
Windows Registry Editor Version 5.00

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\Applications\powershell.exe\shell\open\command] @="\"C:\\WINDOWS\\system32\\WindowsPowerShell\\v1.0\\powershell.exe\"
-file \"%1\""
```

Problem solved.

Comment: Though this works, this is not recommended. MS made .ps1 associated with a text editor (notepad) for a reason. Best practice, if you want to run .ps*, explicitly call PowerShell and the name of the script. Double click is just opening you up to unnecessary risks of random users, poping bad code.

Comment: Sorry for the late reply. I forgot to reply to this, but I just wanted to say, that it works flawlessly. Thanks a lot